# Laptop for media and light gaming

Tags: laptop, ssd

I'd like a fast start up and decent display. Maybe light gaming.

I was thinking:

- SSD
- 8/16GB RAM
- 15.6" HD Screen

Budget under £400.

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists.  The cheapest laptop Newegg has that meets your criteria costs $1200.

Comment: I got close with this:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00YRY4MHM/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=N21XRYLEM8NJ&coliid=IIIA9A4YZA3OV
Just no SSD

Comment: Can you define "light gaming". You might consider GTA 5 on medium settings "light gaming".

Comment: Gaming is an after thought really. I'm more interested in a decent build, SSD, decent screen...etc However I do play PC games, I own GTA4, Skyrim, and other slightly older games, and if I could play them, it would be a bonus, but I'm not too bothered as I have my PC and PS4 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

- [Lenovo G50-80](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/g-series/g50-80/) with ex. i7-5500U/16GB/240 SSD
- Dell Inspiron 5548 i5-5200U/8GB/128SDD+500HDD if you do not like wasting money on DVD (well over the budget, good graphics)
- ASUS R556LJ-XO603D-8 i3-5005U/8GB/128SSD+1TB GF920 (well under the budget, good graphics)

Comment: The ASUS sounds good, but I can't see anywhere selling it for the UK with a quick Google search.